# How do I get C++ to work with Code:Blocks?

Tags: programming

I installed code blocks, selected a GNU/gcc compiler, and created a new empty project and file. When I try to execute a basic Hello World program, no console window pops up and no errors are generated.

Answer (score 3):

Actually Codeblocks has sometime a problem like the one you mention. what I do is click on **New File** and select **Empty File** or just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and then SAVE the file with some name .cpp. Like example.cpp.

THEN  you start writing the code for it. When finished press **F9** for it to Build and Run.

IF by any chance you do not have g++ in your Ubuntu (In my ubuntu it does not come by default) just install it by `sudo apt-get install g++` or better yet the build essential tools `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and close and open CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when g++ was not installed. Codeblocks actually uses g++, not gcc.
Try installing the "g++" package.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the 'build-essential' package. Open a terminal and type: `sudo apt-get install build-essential` You can also install it with synaptic package manager or with the ubuntu software center.